# How does Kerberos work with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, kerberos

Suppose I have four computers, Laptop, Server1, Server2, Kerberos server:

- I log in using PuTTY or SSH from L to S1, giving my username / password
- From S1 I then SSH to S2. No password is needed as Kerberos authenticates me

Describe all the important SSH and KRB5 protocol exchanges: "L sends username to S1", "K sends ... to S1" etc.

(This question is intended to be community-edited; please improve it *for the non-expert reader*.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First login:

- L sends username and SSH authentication request to S1
- S1 returns available SSH authentication mechanisms, with "password" as one of them
- L picks "password" and sends the plain password to S1
- S1 gives username and password to PAM stack.
- On S1, PAM (usually `pam_krb5` or `pam_sss`) requests a TGT (ticket-granting ticket) from the Kerberos KDC.

  1. S1 obtains a TGT.

     - Old style (without preauth): S1 sends an AS-REQ and receives a AS-REP containing the TGT.
     - New style (with preauth): S1 uses your password to encrypt the current time stamp, and attaches it to the AS-REQ. The server decrypts the timestamp and verifies that it is within the allowed time skew; if decryption fails, the password is immediately rejected. Otherwise, a TGT is returned in the AS-REP.
  2. S1 attempts to decrypt the TGT using a key generated from your password. If the decryption succeeds, the password is accepted as correct.
  3. The TGT is stored to a newly created credential cache. (You can inspect the `$KRB5CCNAME` environment variable to find the ccache, or use `klist` to list its contents.)
- S1 uses PAM to perform authorization checks (configuration-dependent) and open the session.

  - If `pam_krb5` is called in authorization stage, it checks whether `~/.k5login` exists. If it does, it must list the client Kerberos principal. Otherwise, the only allowed principal is `username@DEFAULT-REALM`.

Second login:

- S1 sends username and SSH authn request to S2
- S2 returns available auth mechs, one of them being "gssapi-with-mic" <sup>1</sup>
- S1 requests a ticket for `host/s2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM`, by sending a TGS-REQ with the TGT to the KDC, and receiving a TGS-REP with the service ticket from it.
- S1 generates an "AP-REQ" (authentication request) and sends it to S2.
- S2 attempts to decrypt the request. If it succeeds, authentication is done. (PAM is not used for authentication.)

  - Other protocols such as LDAP may choose to encrypt further data transmission with a "session key" that was included with the request; however, SSH has already negotiated its own encryption layer.
- If authentication succeeds, S2 uses PAM to perform authorization checks and open the session, same as S1.
- If credential forwarding was enabled and the TGT has the "forwardable" flag, then S1 requests a copy of the user's TGT (with the "forwarded" flag set) and sends it to S2, where it gets stored to a new ccache. This allows recursive Kerberos-authenticated logins.

Note that you can obtain TGTs locally as well. On Linux, you can do this using **`kinit`**, then connect using `ssh -K`. For Windows, if you are logged in to a Windows AD domain, Windows does that for you; otherwise, [MIT Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/) can be used. PuTTY 0.61 supports using both Windows (SSPI) and MIT (GSSAPI), although you must enable forwarding (delegation) manually.

---

<sup>1</sup> `gssapi-keyex` is also possible but was not accepted into official OpenSSH.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relationship between the password, TGT, and response from the KDC? It's not clear _how_ PAM decides whether the password is correct.

Comment: NOTE: This sentence is incorrect: "S1 sends a TGS-REQ and receives a TGS-REP containing the TGT." Incorrect because TGT's come as part of the AS_REP. A Service Ticket will come back with the TGS_REPn

Comment: Recent versions of OpenSSH have key exchange. I think 4.2p1 was the first version to have the patches. (http://sxw.org.uk/computing/patches/openssh.html)

Comment: No they don't. Those are _third-party_ patches. That's what I meant by "not accepted into official OpenSSH"

Answer (score 1):

To put the long story short: ideally, Kerberos tickets should be obtained on your terminal (L), either with `kinit` command or as part of the local login sequence in a so-called "single sign-on" setup. The remote systems (S1, S2) would then be accessible without password prompts. A chained access (L→S1→S2) would be possible by employing a technique known as "ticket forwarding". Such a setup requires, in particular, the KDC to be directly accessible from the terminal (L).

The other answer by *grawity* explains this approach in details.

Answer (score -2):

The only non-obvious step here would be that there is a PAM module on S1 that used your credentials to perform a `kinit` and gets you a ticket granting ticket from K (client authentication). Then, when you SSH to S2 using Kerberos authentication, an client service authentication takes place. I don't see the benefit of going through all the tedious exchanges message by message.

Throw a `-vvv` on your ssh command if you want to see every message and read the [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) of Kerberos.

Comment: Answering a question which asks for *details* with "I don't see the benefit of elaborating on the details" seems quite rude to me.